# svg bar chart fails to render on plnkr

Tags: d3.js

Not sure if this is a plnkr issue or an issue with my code.. although the console is not showing any errors.

I am writting a little svg script and it does not render.

```
var w = 300;
var h = 100;
var padding = 2;

var dataset = [5, 10, 14, 20, 25];
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);


svg.selectAll('rect')
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append('rect')
.attr('x', function(d, i) {
  return i * (w/dataset.length);
})
.attr('y', function(d) {
  return h - (d);
})
  .attr("width", w/ dataset.length - padding)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d;
  });
```

Plnkr here: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/X7KomlmOVS6C0zhNL19b

Comment: The problem is that you're running the script before the window is loaded, you'll need to put that all in a window.load or doc ready

Comment: ohh..how many times have I dont this mistake.. I usually recover from this soon.. but since d3 is new to me.. i didn't think of anything else.. I would mark you answer as correct.. but it's a comment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run it inside a document.ready or wait till the window is loaded. http://plnkr.co/edit/TmFWndyCgLk7GYEng7XP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script data-require="d3@*" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

and in the JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var w = 300;
var h = 100;
var padding = 2;

var dataset = [5, 10, 14, 20, 25];
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

console.log('running the plnkr');
svg.selectAll('rect')
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append('rect')
.attr('x', function(d, i) {
  return i * (w/dataset.length);
})
.attr('y', function(d) {
  return h - (d * 4);
})
  .attr("width", w/ dataset.length - padding)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d * 4;
  });

});
```